# Text over an image with sql & php

Tags: php, html

how can i place my outcome text field placed in the image

[image]

the code i made:

```
> echo "<img id='image' src='http://i.imgur.com/qqzaa4N.png'></a> <p id='text'>€ ".$row['total']."</p>";
```

I was thinking about div class but that did not work i'm getting

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

the end result needs to be something like this one:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWror.png

---

It did work after I changed my css to:

```
#image {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 200px;
}
#text {
  z-index: 100;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 350px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

And my script to:

```
echo '<img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/qqzaa4N.png"></a> <p id="text">€ '.$row['total'].'</p>';
```

Comment: use position absolute for text, for error, Google.

Comment: code something like: `<a href="yoururl">
<img id='image' src='http://i.imgur.com/qqzaa4N.png'></a>
<p id='text'>€ <?=$row['total']?></p>`

Comment: for syntax error, share your full code

Comment: still missing starting `<a>`

Comment: and your #image position must be `position: relative;` not `absolute`

Comment: Thanks buddy fixed that 2

Comment: good now??????  ?

Comment: Oh Yes it did work

Comment: great, now choose the best answer mark as accepted... this will help to future visitors

Answer (score 2):

you did not specify exactly what you want, but if you want to place the text over the image try to write the code bellow, don't forget to replace `42` with the value you want `row['total']`.

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
.image-text{
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<img id='image' src='http://i.imgur.com/qqzaa4N.png'>
<p class='image-text' id='text'>€ 42</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css.

```
<style>
.container {
position: relative;
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
```

`}.tag {`

```
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
right: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
 </style>

<div class="container">
<div class="tag">Featured</div>
<img src="yourimagesoucre">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

write this instead

```
echo '<img id="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/qqzaa4N.png"></a> <p id="text">€ '.$row['total'].'</p>';
```